# multiple key with same DKIM selector?

Tags: dkim

I've got two separate DKIM records which use the same selector.
One is for MailChimp which uses "k1" as selector, and the other one is an old record for which I have not found out yet what it is for.

Is there a way to have two separate keys in the same DKIM record with the same selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RFC 6376 says the following (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.6.2.2):

> TXT RRs MUST be unique for a particular selector name; that is, if there are multiple records in an RRset, the results are undefined.

So no, you can not put two separate keys in the DKIM record with the same selector, at least not at the same time. And even if they are not used at the same time, I would strongly recommend to give each key its own selector.